# What is the meaning of"that broke meter"in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of "that broke meter" in this context? Does it have a meaning like way too much or out of control?

> Yes. By the time I came to Life Studies I’d been writing my
>      autobiography and also writing poems **that broke meter**. I’d been
>      doing a lot of reading aloud. I went on a trip to the West Coast and
>      read at least once a day and sometimes twice for fourteen days, and
>      more and more I found that I was simplifying my poems. If I had a
>      Latin quotation I’d translate it into English. If adding a couple of
>      syllables in a line made it clearer I’d add them, and I’d make little
>      changes just impromptu as I read. That seemed to improve the reading.

*([Source](https://advancedenglishyear11.wikispaces.com/file/view/Robert+Lowell+-+Comedic+Life+Studies%5B3%5D.pdf))*

Comment: In the poetical context it could mean poems that did not respect the  rhythm pattern. See the definition of *Meter* 1. in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meter).

Answer (score 1):

In poetry, *metre* is:

> [the basic rhythmic structure of a verse or lines in verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)).

And you could look at [this definition](https://literarydevices.net/meter/) and examples on *Literary Devices*.

So once you know the person saying those words is the American poet [Robert Lowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lowell) and you know that *Life Studies* as mentioned in [this interview](https://www.theparisreview.org/interviews/4664/robert-lowell-the-art-of-poetry-no-3-robert-lowell) showed a change in the way he wrote poetry, you understand that **writing poems that broke meter** means "writing poems that broke with the traditional way of respecting metre in traditional English poetry".

This excerpt from the article about [Robert Lowell](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poets/detail/robert-lowell) on the *Poetry Foundation* deals with this aspect of Lowell's art:

> In the 1940s he wrote intricate and tightly patterned poems that incorporated traditional meter and rhyme; in the late 1950s when he published Life Studies, he began to write startlingly original personal or "confessional" poetry in much looser forms and meters;